# facing issue in downloading aftrifacts from afrtifactory using ansible script through jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

Getting permission denied error when try to execute the ansible script in Jenkins pipeline

[Jenkins error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJZrQ.png)

**below is my Jenkins pipeline script**

```
node {
    ansiblePlaybook colorized: true, extras: '-e ear_url="ARTIFACTORY URL here"', installation: 'ansible-2.7', playbook: '/etc/ansible/playbooks/deploy.yml', sudo: true
}
```

**ANSIBLE SCRIPT**

```
hosts: tibco
  user: root
  sudo: yes
  connection: ssh
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
   my_ear: "{{ear_url}}"
   ear_location: /tmp/EARS  
  tasks:
    - name: Download the ear file from the artifactory
      get_url: 
        url: "{{my_ear}}" 
        dest: "{{ear_location}}"
```

Please help me out.

Comment: How about setting correct credentials (key file for root user)?

Comment: What do you see in the artifactory.log and request.log in Artufactory? As @KonstantinSuvorov said, it seems that you do not have credentials to Artifactory and therefore getting permission denied.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user used has write access on the mentioned folder "/etc/ansible/playbooks"